# How can I imitate gnome gsettings functionality in KDE Plasma using the command line?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

I have heard about `kwriteconfig` as begin the equivalent for `gsettings`.

I'd like to be able to imitate the functionality shown in my script for GNOME in KDE Plasma.

## Gnome Script

Setup gnome to my liking.

- set window theme
- set icon theme
- set cursor appearance
- set window button layout

### Code

```
#!/bin/bash

#yaourt -Sy
declare -a Pacs=(
'macos-icon-theme'
'macos-arc-white-theme'
'capitaine-cursors'
'gtk-theme-united-gnome'
);
for i in ${Pacs[@]}; do
  yaourt -S $i --noconfirm --needed
done

# List gnome installed themes
#gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface
#gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.interface 
#gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name
# GTK
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "United-Ubuntu"
# Icons
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "macOS"
# Windows
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ""
# Cursor
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "Capitain"
# Buttons left (uses : separator )
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"
# Shell Theme
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "United-Arch"

# lightdm login screen
yaourt -S lightdm-webkit-theme-litarvan
```